# Pattern matching for a class name

Tags: css

I've got

```
<span class="section-number-3">1.1.</span>
```

but then my page generation software (Emacs org-mode html export) can produce `...section-number-x...` where `x` can be any number. Is there a way in CSS to have a generic

```
.section-number-x {...
```

for any `x` that might be generated? Obviously, I could create a separate definition for each possible `x`, but I'm thinking there must be something more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use attribute selector, where you can search against substrings from start, from end, or everywhere in attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

In your specific case, it should be:

```
span[class^="section-number-"]{ ... }
```

what will find "section-number-" substring from the start of css class of any span element.

check attached link for more examples

Comment: Please add some explanation on how that selector _exactly_ because `^=` is a pretty special function which deserves to be explained.

Comment: I've updated my response, added link to attribute selector documentation with more examples